# TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined using vue.js and axios

Tags: vue.js, axios

I am trying to pass data via an axios' post in a vue method and getting the error:

> "signinVue.js:60 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined"

**Vue script:**

```js
new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    data:{
        email:'',
        code:'',
    },
    methods:{
        signin:function(){
            console.log(this.email + ' ' + this.access);
            let url = '../App/testConnection.php';
            this.axios.post(url, {email:this.email, code:this.code})
                .then((response) =>{
                  console.log(response);
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
                //console.log(this.email + ' ' + this.access);
                //alert(this.email);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you post how do you import the `axios` package?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Axios is usually registered as a **global** variable, so, instead of:

```js
this.axios.post(url, {email:this.email, code:this.code})
```

you should **use**:

```js
axios.post(url, {email:this.email, code:this.code})
```

Notice the `this.` is gone.

Note: If you wanted to really use Axios via `this.axios`, you should add it to the `Vue` prototype, as such:

```js
Vue.prototype.axios = window.axios; // this will enable this.axios inside Vue instances
new Vue({
// ...
```

But this is sort of a bad practice. If you with to add properties to the Vue prototype like that, the suggested approach is to use a `$` or `_` prefix, like:

```js
Vue.prototype.$axios = window.axios; // this will enable this.$axios inside Vue instances
```

Because if you set `Vue.prototype.axios`, it could conflict with some (unlikely, yes) data property you have named `axios`, as in :`data:{email:'', code:'', axios: 'w00t'},`.